# Let $\Omega$ be a star-shaped open set of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Under which conditions is $\Omega$ analytically diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: differential-topology

In this post

[A star shaped open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184453/a-star-shaped-open-set-in-mathbbrn-is-diffeomorphic-to-mathbbrn)

I found a proof that $\Omega$ is always diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. In which cases can such a diffeomorphism  be analytical?

Answer (score 3):

There is a general theorem (Morrey and Grauert) stating that if two real-analytic manifolds are diffeomorphic then they are real-analytically isomorphic.

H. Grauert, On Levi’s problem and the imbedding of real analytic manifolds, Ann. of Math., 68 (1958), 460-472.

C. B. Morrey, The analytic embedding of abstract real analytic manifolds, Ann. of Math., 68 (1958), 159-201.