# Subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are convex, closed, and have non-empty interiors?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, compactness

Can someone give me some guidance with this problem? Thanks.

Suppose that $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ are convex, closed, and have non-empty interiors.

1. Prove that $A, B$ are the closure of their interiors.
2. If $A, B$ are compact, prove that they are homeomorphic.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/why-does-a-convex-set-have-the-same-interior-points-as-its-closure and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165629/proof-that-convex-open-sets-in-mathbbrn-are-homeomorphic

Comment: Is there a typo in the title of this question?  (What is R2?)

Comment: I think it's meant to be R in both title and question, or R^2 in both . You can also put R^n for any finite n, in both.